# Angular Material forms background color

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm newbie in Angular and Angular material. I'm creating a form and want to change the background color for example for Red.

But instead of simply changing the background color, the red color get over the form.

```js
<form class="example-form" style="background-color:red">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here is an example on stackblitz: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ka5hm7?file=src/app/input-overview-example.html)

Can someone say me, how is the correct way for setting the background color?

Thank you!

Comment: The question is unclear for me. You changed the background color with `style="background-color:red"`. What does _"But instead of simply changing the background color, the red color get over the form."_ mean? I see a form with red background in your stackblitz link.

Comment: Yeah, the background color is red, and all elements also are red, but i want  all elements on the form remain in the default color. In my example the background color is like overlay layer over elements.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The form fields are grey and transparent. You can see the dark areas. Transparency means when you change the background color of the form the element changes its color, too. You can't change the background of the form without changing the background to keep the default color.

Comment: Ok, it is possible to disable the transparency?

Comment: The default color of the elements is `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.04);`. That's black with 96% transparency. On a white background it's pretty similar to `background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);` without transparency.

Comment: The next problem is you have to style `<div class="mat-form-field-flex">`. You can't access it from the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default color of the elements is `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)`. That's black with 96% transparency. On white background it's similar to `rgb(245, 245, 245)`. You can add the CSS rule

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-flex {
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
```

to change the background color of the divs and keep the default color on all backgrounds.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ka5hm7-jxen6p?file=src/app/input-overview-example.css

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting only the form-field to change, add the styles on the form-field rather than on the form. I updated your stackblitz. Check here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ka5hm7-sreotx?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html

Comment: OP wants to style the form without input fields, not the form fields. That's different areas.